# Using async closure as lambda functions is a bit hard

Tags: rust, lambda, closures

I'm trying to reproduce an error I'm having on my small app in Rust.

I'm trying to use async closure as lambda functions (very tipical in other languages).

But I just found out that this is a bit difficult in Rust:

REPL: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/bcwggm.

Error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:55:9
   |
54 |       let result = player_change_name(&|musts| {
   |                                         ------ return type of closure is Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = Result<Player, ()>> + Send + '2)>>
   |                                         |
   |                                         has type `PlayerMusts<'1>`
55 | /         Box::pin(async {
56 | |             let o = Player {
57 | |                 id: musts.actual.id.clone(),
58 | |                 name: "Frank".to_string(),
...  |
62 | |             Ok(o)
63 | |         })
   | |__________^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Code:

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.26.0", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
*/

use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin};

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub team: Option<String>,
}

struct PlayerMusts<'a> {
    pub actual: &'a Player,
    pub other: &'a str,
}

async fn player_change_name<'a>(
    lambda: &(dyn 'a
          + Fn(PlayerMusts) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Player, ()>> + Send + 'a>>
          + Sync),
) -> Result<Player, ()> {
    // I need to await for many things in here

    // Eg. for DB connection pool...
    // let mut db_connection = pool.begin().await?;

    // Here I can query the actual player, I'm faking it now...
    let actual = Player {
        id: "1".to_string(),
        name: "Bob".to_string(),
        team: None,
    };

    let worked_player = lambda(PlayerMusts {
        actual: &actual,
        other: "Other",
    })
    .await?;

    // I'm saving the lambda result here, I'm faking it now...
    // let result = db_connection.save(&worked_player, &actual).await?;
    let result = worked_player;

    // db_connection.save_and_close().await?;

    Ok(result)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let result = player_change_name(&|musts| {
        Box::pin(async {
            let o = Player {
                id: musts.actual.id.clone(),
                name: "Frank".to_string(),
                team: None,
            };

            Ok(o)
        })
    })
    .await?;

    dbg!(result);

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is putting the lifetime on `player_change_name`.  This function should not accept a lifetime parameter, because it's too restrictive at this point -- the caller has to choose the lifetime, and there is *no possible lifetime* the caller can choose that will make sense.

The function itself doesn't capture the lifetime `'a` either, so that restriction is also unnecessary.

What you want to say regarding the lifetimes is that "for *any possible* lifetime `'a`, this closure should accept a `PlayerMusts<'a>` and return a future that captures `'a`.  You need a [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) or HRTB:

```
async fn player_change_name(
    lambda: &(dyn for<'a> Fn(PlayerMusts<'a>) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Player, ()>> + Send + 'a>> + Sync),
) -> Result<Player, ()> {
```

Note the `for<'a>` syntax, which creates the HRTB.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but I think something is still broken: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/hsdahn.

Comment: Your suggestion works and I need to study it. But now the problem is on the caller. Why?

Comment: @FredHors The code in that question is exactly the same as the code in this question. When I apply my change to your code, [it compiles and runs successfully](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b63d1ea200614cdce3e0ecff9560926).

Comment: Nope, the code is slighter different, I introduced traits to the question to better reproduce my local issue.

Comment: @FredHors Okay... when I apply the fix in my answer to that code, [it also works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e6a104ec30f4db3da31412e0e09cdb8e). It's not clear to me what "the problem is on the caller" means because I cannot reproduce the issue with either version of the code after applying the fix in my answer.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault in reproduction. I managed to reproduce it now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75871841/using-async-closure-as-lambda-functions-with-hrtb.

Comment: Can you please help me understand?

Comment: are you sill there?